# Inflate layout from ApplicationContext (i.e., in a ContentProvider)

Tags: android

To implement share pic functionality, I want to render a `Layout` (i.e., xml configured UI) to an image (i.e., PNG) in a `ContentProvider`.

The concept: I want to generate the share pic in the ContentProvider on request, so I don't need to store (and later delete) it as temporary file.
And I want to use a `Layout` as it is easy to change, can render to different resolutions/ orientations, and can adjust text sizes automatically.

Reduced example:

```
    public void render(@NonNull OutputStream outputStream) {
        int imageHeight = imageWidth / 4 * 3;
        
        SharePictureBinding viewBinding = SharePictureBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context));

        // Set some text properties here
        ...

        // prepare rendering
        View view = viewBinding.getRoot();
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(imageWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(imageHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        view.layout(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

        // draw
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

        view.draw(canvas);

        // store
        bitmap.compress(compressFormat, 100, outputStream);
}
```

Accessing this from a ContentProvider's context (i.e., `ApplicationContext`), works for *K9-Mail* and *Element* (files are shared properly) but not for *Tusky* (file cannot be read).

BUT if I use this functionality, I get always the following exceptions (2nd one repeated about 8 times) - independent if the actual image rendering worked (i.e., can be used by the receiving application):

```
2021-07-27 06:39:41.705 17701-17933/de.dennisguse.opentracks.debug E/ContextImpl: Tried to access visual service LayoutInflater from a non-visual Context:de.dennisguse.opentracks.Startup@a3897e0 Visual services, such as WindowManager, WallpaperService or LayoutInflater should be accessed from Activity or other visual Context. Use an Activity or a Context created with Context#createWindowContext(int, Bundle), which are adjusted to the configuration and visual bounds of an area on screen.
    java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Tried to access visual service LayoutInflater from a non-visual Context:de.dennisguse.opentracks.Startup@a3897e0

2021-07-27 06:39:41.819 17701-17933/de.dennisguse.opentracks.debug E/ViewConfiguration: Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context:de.dennisguse.opentracks.Startup@a3897e0UI constants, such as display metrics or window metrics, must be accessed from Activity or other visual Context. Use an Activity or a Context created with Context#createWindowContext(int, Bundle), which are adjusted to the configuration and visual bounds of an area on screen
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context:de.dennisguse.opentracks.Startup@a3897e0
```

Current work in progress: https://github.com/OpenTracksApp/OpenTracks/pull/888

Comment: `non-visual Context` is crucial in here, maybe you should start some `ForegroundService` to take this bitmap

Comment: @snachmsm how can I start a ForegroundService from a ContentProvider and reply in a synchronous way?

Comment: synced version is practically impossible to achieve, just thought about passing rest of task to proper `Context`

Comment: That seems to be new. Are you testing this on API level 30? Do you get the same logs on older versions? Did you investigate the suggestion in the first error message: [`Context#createWindowContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#createWindowContext(int,%20android.os.Bundle))?

Comment: Yes, targetSDKVersion is 30, but I see it on devices running API29 (aka Android10) and API30. I tried to use createWindowContext, but this requires a `Display`.

Comment: Well, I don't see it anywhere on 10, but this appears to be at least a relatively recent `StrictMode` addition, and AFAICT there is currently no public access to switch that on or off.

Comment: @MikeM. I saw this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191503798 disabling StrictMode hides this exception...

Comment: That issue definitely needs more stack trace. In all seriousness, though, if their ads are tripping this, it should get pretty quick attention. After a little more poking around, it looks like this might be something to be introduced publicly in 31: [`IncorrectContextUseViolation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/strictmode/IncorrectContextUseViolation), [`detectIncorrectContextUse()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder#detectIncorrectContextUse()). Maybe they fumbled trying to insert this functionality quietly in the background?

Comment: Yeah, if you can entirely disable it, that'll do it. Doesn't look like we'll be able to toggle that specific violation until 31, though.

Comment: @MikeM. StrictMode does not need to be disabled. The actual issue was a typo in the mime type - the exceptions have no impact (so far). Thanks to you all!

Comment: Oh, right. I kinda forgot that you mentioned that it was failing altogether sometimes. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use an ApplicationContext (i.e., a non-visual context) to inflate a layout until now (tested with API30).
**BUT** this is not recommended and API31 actually introduces an exception for this `IncorrectContextUseViolation`.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/strictmode/IncorrectContextUseViolation

The exceptions in the questions are triggered by enabling `StrictMode.detectIncorrectContextUse()` and do not have any effect on runtime behavior.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder#detectIncorrectContextUse()
So, even if you see these exceptions in Logcat, the layout may still be successfully inflated.

Side note: it was a Layer 8 issue as the mime type was incorrect and thus the rendered content was not accepted by the application it was send to. The exceptions were just misleading.